# Where am I gaining 6px height retrieving buddypress avatar

Tags: buddypress

I'm currently in the process of building a social network based site using buddypress and when the user is logged in I want to display their avatar in my header. To do this I've used this code.

```
<div id="avatar">
    <a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>">
        <?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=30&height=30' ); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

It may seem like a small detail and something I can probably work around if I really needed to, but I would love to find out what was causing this seeming mysterious 6px gain I'm suffering from.

You can see the site i'm working on by visiting [www.vwrx-project.co.uk](http://www.vwrx-project.co.uk). I think you'd have to sign in, in order to see the avatar display, which your more than welcome to do.

Once the theme development is complete I'll be erasing the entire database to start afresh after testing anyway.

Comment: I would probably ask this on the Buddypress.org site as it all depends on this function `bp_loggedin_user_avatar()`

Comment: I'll have to look into doing that then, thank you for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: You could always see what comes out the other end and adjust the 6px size using CSS something like `#avatar img { height:6px; width:6px }`

Comment: Since I've posted I've done more testing and still can't figure it out. I thought it could have been to do with the "href" but taking that out makes no difference.

Comment: I've done some testing on the code and it should be fine. I have experimented with the sizes ie `type=thumb&width=20&height=20` If this is making no difference to the size there will be CSS that is overriding it. Right click on the image in your browser and inspect element - check what styles are altering it.

Comment: After inspecting the elements again it seem's that multiple line-heights have been added from the different stylesheets loaded by wordpress. I've now added a line-height:0; element to the stylesheet now.

I literally went through removing each and every applied style one by one in order to find this.

Thank you all for the help/advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your line heights being set at 1.5.

You need to set this in your CSS:

```
#avatar {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Also, if you want to get your other buttons "Logout" and the username, you will need to set the specific height on the parent DIV, which should be 50px, being as though your image is 30px, and you have 10px padding on top and bottom

Comment: Thank you, after a lot of testing I found it to be the same issue

Comment: lol yeah just saw your comment, right after i posted mine :P glad you got it figured out

Comment: I figured that was the case, but as yours was an answer and not just a comment it gave me the opportunity to accept the answer too :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - as nothing I said was an actual answer and I didn't have time to register on your site, the comments were the best place for it!